# Using a global (static) variable in Java

Tags: java

I have a need to share a variable between two classes in the same package. I would not like to debate the "why" I'm using a global variable. I avoid them normally at all cost.

My understanding is that I need to declare my variable as static, and that any variable declared in such a manner is available to all classes in the package. I am using a Java library called Lanterna that is used to create text-based GUIs. In order write characters to the screen buffer, I have to create an object (which I called screen) of the Screen type. The two declarations below are placed near the top of my entry class (not in the constructor).

```
public static Terminal terminal = TerminalFacade.createTerminal(System.in, System.out, Charset.forName("UTF8"));

public static Screen screen = new Screen(terminal);
```

The types Terminal and Screen are declared as import statements at the top of my program. I don't receive any errors in Eclipse with these statement. In the class where I attempt to access the screen object, I get an error saying Multiple Markers at this line, screen cannot be resolved.

If any additional information needs to be provided please let me know.

Comment: You get an error saying you have multiple errors. Please tell us what they are.

Comment: Just to clarify `static` does *not* dictate access level, it ensures that the variable belongs to the class itself (and not each instance), and is accessible by the syntax `MyClass.myVar`. The modifiers `public`, `private`, `protected`, and default (no keyword) are what control visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `terminal` and `screen` are in-scope everywhere, they are not automatically imported, and you have to reference them by the class that contains them.

For example, if you declared them in class `Myclass`, you would access them by eg.

```
MyClass.terminal.frobnicate();
```

Alternatively, though this is not standard practice in most cases, you can import them like so:

```
import static myPackage.MyClass.terminal;
```

Then you will be able to simply reference `terminal` without clarifying that you refer to `MyClass`'s `terminal`, and not some other class's static field called `terminal`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of import you need a `static import` (The [Static Import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) Java guide says, in part, *The static import construct allows unqualified access to static members without inheriting from the type containing the static members*). Something like (obviously with your entry-class)

```
import static com.foo.EntryClass.terminal;
import static com.foo.EntryClass.screen;
```